# Recovery from user@1000service error

Tags: boot, 14.10, systemd-logind

My system crashed.  When I rebooted the disk check reported errors.  I asked it to fix the errors.  My system will now not boot to login in graphics mode.

After the screen flashes I see

```
saned disabled
edit /etc/default/saned
```

The system then stalls.  I finally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in from TTY1.  I then see messages:

```
[96.263452] systemd-logind failed to start unit user@1000.service unknown unit
[96.263892] Failed to start service unknown unit: user@1000.service
```

The `/etc/default/saned` file looks OK.

*How should I restore the system to allow it to boot completely?*

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do right now is:

1. boot from a LiveCD,
2. back-up all your data
3. test whether your drives are OK

   - `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`
   - `sudo smartctl --scan`
   - For all devices that come up on the previous command to a `sudo smartctl --all /dev/XdY` where X and Y are the letters that come up in the previous step
4. re-install.

   - **Replace any drives that show a "fail"**

Before you reinstall, have [a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) so that this will not happen any more in the future, but that you might just restore a system back-up when something like that happens...

Comment: this is so upsetting.  i don't even have any data on that one... but to redo the whole install will take forever.  omg.  balls.

Comment: Expecially the "replace any bad drives" is the most important bit.  Emphasis added after-the-fact..

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get remove upstart
```

If it is ubuntu16.04 and you have installed upstart. Worked for me.