# GUI wont allow log-in, but CLI works fine

Tags: login, gui

I'm having the same issue found here (and tried to suggested solution, but that didn't help any):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/556873/unable-to-log-in-gui-mode-in-ubuntu

But it won't let me comment on that one, says I don't have enough reputation.  I used to be able to use the GUI all the time, but then after applying some patches a few months ago, it stopped letting me log-in to the GUI. I hoped it was a temporary bug that would eventually get fixed, but it's still a problem, and preventing me form using the desktop GUI (and thus some programs).

The CLI works fine, but in the GUI, I select my user name, put in the password, it acts like it's logging in, then the screen goes black, and eventually it goes back to the log-in screen.

I'm running "Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" and have tried applying the latest patches with "apt upgrade", but the problem persists.

The only error message I see when logging in on the CLI:

> [    ##.######] systemd-login[1742]: Failed to start user service,
>   ignoring: Unknown unit: user@1000.service

I put #'s in there because that number seems to change every time.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

If I login to the CLI, then run "startx", it does basically the same thing, dumping me back to the CLI.

Here's the only error message I see in the output:

> xinit: connection to X server lost

Comment: (although it doesn't recommend anything except a reinstall) Possible duplicate of [Recovery from user@1000service error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/580298/recovery-from-user1000service-error)

Comment: Yeah, my system boots fine, so I don't think I need a reinstall.  I gives me a log-in both CLI and GUI. The difference is that I cannot log-in via the GUI, it goes black, then jumps back to the log-in screen.

Comment: Your desktop is broken and you need to re-install from _CLI_. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` or modify to suit your desktop version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried the reinstall just now, and the behavior has not changed. Even rebooted, no difference.

Comment: What would be involved in the other suggestion to "modify to suit your desktop version"?

Comment: 'to suit your desktop version' means that if you want gnome or KDE - then the package name is slightly different (it doesn't solve the problem). I think we must find which package installs the `user@.service` into `/lib/systemd/system` or whatever.